# Drag selecting text fails

Tags: 15.10, ubuntu-mate

I am running Wily 15.10 with the MATE desktop.

I'm not sure entirely when this started happening, it may have just been after a `sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, but it had to have been at least a week ago I think.

I didn't understand the problem at first, I thought it might be a hardware issue. And it was merely annoying, and I had important things to do I guess.

The issue seems to be that **none** of the programs that I use, including MATE Terminal, Pluma text editor, or Firefox, recognize a drag-select operation anymore. This includes, text in the text editor, text anywhere in the console terminal, text on a webpage, text in a text entry form on a webpage, or text in the address bar of the webbrowser.

They *all* recognize, double clicking on text to select a word or an entire line. They all recognize the "select all" option. And they can actually do copy paste. It's only that *drag-selecting* appears to have been disabled somehow.

I also cannot properly drag windows around by dragging their title bars. It's as though the click always misses or isn't recognized. I can only manipulate their positions now by minimizing or maximizing them.

How does one go about troubleshooting an issue like this?

I've been using Ubuntu for about 8 years, and I never had a problem like this, so I'm somewhat at a loss.

---

Edit:

I can give a somewhat more detailed description.

When I mouse over some text in say a static webpage, my cursor changes from the "normal" arrow symbol, to the text-cursor symbol, which normally is the cue to me that this is some text I could highlight. However, if I actually press the mouse key and drag the cursor left or right, the text is simply not actually highlighted.

Comment: Have you tried using a different mouse?

Comment: No, I didn't try that. I am using the touchpad built into my Lenovo machine. I tried also using the "red nipple" whatever that thing is called, that doesn't seem to help. I could go buy a USB mouse and try that I guess.

Comment: "red nipple" - https://xkcd.com/243/

Comment: It's probably a hardware issue. I've had lots of mouses fail to scroll, lost their sensitivity or confuse the two buttons. As far as I know, Lenovo offers repairs or replacements for touchpads.

Answer (score 1):

After more fiddling with this, this is what I have determined...

In this Lenovo machine, there is a clickpad rather than a touchpad. There are also, for some reason, physical click buttons located above the clickpad.

Normally I just use the clickpad to click I guess, but sometimes I use the physical buttons.

It appears that the physical buttons just aren't always recognized properly for dragging. If I click the *pad* and drag the cursor, then I can select and drag things just fine. If I click the *button* and drag the cursor, that just doesn't seem to count, although double clicking the physical buttons works.

So this is most likely some kind of hardware configuration issue I guess... sorry for posting a problem that has an obscure resolution like this, maybe it helps someone else...